# How to calculate the inverse of the sum of an identity and a Kronecker product efficiently?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix $K$ which is the sum of a identity and a Kronecker product of two symmetric matrices as following and I want to calculate the inverse of it $K^{-1}$.
\begin{eqnarray}
K=\mathbf{I}_{mn}+XX^\top\otimes YY^\top
\end{eqnarray}
where $X$ and $Y$ are $m\times p$ and $n\times q$ matrices respectively and $m>p,n>q$.

Since the size of Kronecker product of two matrices is the product of their sizes, the matrix to be inverted is very large. **Can this calculation be simplified?**

Using *Woodbury matrix identity*, the matrix to be inverted can be reduced from $mn\times mn$ to $pq\times pq$ as
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\mathbf{I}+XX^\top\otimes YY^\top\right)^{-1}
&=&\left(\mathbf{I}+(X\otimes Y)(X\otimes Y)^\top\right)^{-1}\\\
&=&\mathbf{I}-(X\otimes Y)\left(\mathbf{I}+(X\otimes Y)^\top(X\otimes Y)\right)^{-1}(X\otimes Y)^\top
\end{eqnarray}
However, in my application, $p$ and $q$ are not much less than $m$ and $n$. Thus inverting a $pq\times pq$ matrix is still a consuming work and I want to find a more simple calculation of $K^{-1}$.

Consider the following problem. If there is not the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}_{m\times n}$, we can invert $XX^\top$ and $YY^\top$ respectively and then calculate the Kronecker product as
$$
(XX^\top\otimes YY^\top)^{-1}=(XX^\top)^{-1}\otimes(YY^\top)^{-1}
$$
using the property of Kronecker product. However, if the identity item exists, this property cannot be utilized.

Then my question is that **if there is any way to decompose the calculation of $K^{-1}$ into inverses of some smaller matrices whose size is linear with $m$ and $n$ but not their products? Or is it possible to extract the Kronecker product $\otimes$ out of the inverse?**

If you have any suggestion or idea, please let me know.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If $X$ is $m \times p$ with $m>p$, $(XX^T)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: Do you really need the inverse, or do you just want to solve linear systems with it? The latter task is much easier. For the inverse, I don't think there's anything better than what you already suggested with the Woodbury identity.

Comment: @Federico Poloni, yes, you are right! $(XX^\top)^{-1}$ really does not exist. Thank you!

Comment: @Federico Poloni, thank you for your suggestion. What is more, the purpose that I took that example is to show that I want to simplify the calculation utilizing the property of Kronecker product, however, there is some mistake in it. Thank you!

Comment: @ppyang: So is the thing off or not? Because the original question still makes sense, I think.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg: I am still interested in whether there exists some way to simplify this calculation but I have no idea yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix does not cost too much. Let $PXX^TP=\Lambda_1$, $QYY^TQ=\Lambda_2$ be the spectral decomposition of $XX^T, YY^T$, respectively. Here $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2$ are diagonal and $P, Q$ are orthogonal. Then $$K^{-1}=(P\otimes Q)^T(I+\Lambda_1\otimes \Lambda_2)^{-1}(P\otimes Q).$$

$(I+\Lambda_1\otimes \Lambda_2)^{-1}$ can be read directly.

Comment: You provide an excellent idea that reduce the most complex calculation of an $mn\times mn$ matrix into a $m\times m$ matrix and a $n\times n$ matrix, where the inverse is taken on only a diagonal. I think it solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer by Betrand. But it's easy to verify that the final form should be $K^{-1} = (P\otimes Q)(I + \Lambda_1 \otimes \Lambda_2)^{-1} (P \otimes Q)^T$.

Here is some R code:

```
A = matrix(c(3, 2, 2, 3), ncol = 2)
B = matrix(c(2, 2, 3, 4), ncol = 2)
AA = A %*% t(A)
BB = B %*% t(B)
AA_decomp = eigen(AA)
P = AA_decomp$vectors
LAMB_A = diag(AA_decomp$values)
P %*% LAMB_A %*% t(P)
BB_decomp = eigen(BB)
Q = BB_decomp$vectors
LAMB_B = diag(BB_decomp$values)
Q %*% LAMB_B %*% t(Q)
K = diag(dim(A)[1] * dim(B)[1]) + kronecker(AA, BB)
solve(K)
kronecker(P, Q) %*% solve(diag(dim(A)[1] * dim(B)[1]) + kronecker(LAMB_A, LAMB_B)) %*% t(kronecker(P, Q))
```